# Regex Pattern to match only first sign of a String

Tags: regex, string, match

I want the pattern to match the exactly first sign of a String. The sign can be everything: whitespace, character, digit... but it should be only the first.

**^.{1}** was my guess, but ends in infite loop on string **"123 void"**

```html
public CatchAll(String string) {
  pattern = Pattern.compile("^.");
```

Language is Java,  **^.** loops infitite.

Suggestions for such a pattern?

Comment: What about just [`^.`](https://regex101.com/r/jI5mO5/1)? I feel the problem is not with the regex here. Please provide full relevant Java code you are using.

Comment: What language are you using and how are you implementing it? `^.` should be enough.

Comment: Why use regex at all? If you want the first character of string `s`, just do `s[0]`?

Comment: The comments above are valid, but your regex works fine for me, could you share the code that causes troubles?

Comment: The whole project is kind of a lexer, i have a abstract token and different types implementing it, all with different pattern. This one should match the first sign of a String and save it in his content for later use.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Java:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123 void");
    if(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

However, a *better* approach, since you just want the first character of the string, would be to use the `substring(int start, int finish)` method.

```
    String newStr = "123 void".substring(0, 1);
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

Both Yield `1`.

EDIT: Pending @stribizhev's comment, you can also do:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123 void");
    if(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

However I am not sure if this is what @stribizhev meant.

Comment: I would not use a capturing group here. [Just `^.` and `group(0)` is enough](https://ideone.com/KEYsHA).

Comment: @stribizhev: Could you please provide some more information with regards to your comment?

Comment: Perfectly working in my project. I used matcher.match(), matcher.find() works. However, now all my other patterns do not match anymore ^^. Ideas for that? (Example: other pattern="void" does not match on the string now.

Comment: @l_b: Can you please provide a small example showing your problem?

Comment: Pattern1 = "void"
Pattern2 = "^(.)" 
String = "123 void"

The Algorithm always checks against pattern1, if it do not match against pattern2. Later deletes the matched part from string and starts again. With the change to match.find(), it fails to match pattern1 in the example. Well, it matches every part of the string with pattern2 =)

Comment: @l_b: `void` is a valid match for `^.` Can you please edit your question and provide a simple working example of your problem?